# Разметка страницы с ошибкой ( 404, 500, желтый экран смерти )

Tags: asp.net, html, css, разметка

Вечер добрый. В процессе прикручивания логов к сайту встала проблема с заглушкой: не получается сверстать простенькую страничку с ошибкой, все выходит как то кривоватенько. Подскажите сайты с простенькими макетами или даже с примерами разметки разметки на тему (знаю про макеты на `htmlbook`, но хотелось бы посмотреть пример расширенный и симпатичный).

Comment: [Несколько примеров креативного подхода при создании «Error 404» страниц][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142038/